# How to interpret "Why do you think I did this?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does this sentence,

> Why do you think I did this?

mean

- Why do you think this is done by me? or
- What do you think is the reason I did this?

Comment: It could mean either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would depend on where you put the emphasis.

You could verbally emphasise:

- Why do you think **I** did this? (to ask why you, and not somebody else)
- Why do **you** think I did this? (to ask if they had a different opinion to someone else)
- Why do you think I did **this**? (to ask why they think you chose to do 'this' and not something else).

In written English, emphasis of this kind is normally shown by *italics*.

Comment: Don't forget the emphasis on "why"!

Answer (score 1):

It could mean either. In fact, it could have 7 distinct meanings depending on which of the 7 words is stressed!